# Move or create new EFI partition on different disk

Tags: linux, windows, partitioning, grub, uefi

i have a windows install on disk 1, and arch linux on disk 2,
i use the default 100 MB windows boot partition on disk 1 for both windows boot manager as well as grub to boot linux (os prober failed to add windows to grub, but thats of no issue)

id like to somehow make a boot partition an disk 2 and put grub there (only grub, i dont want to change windows boot mgr), but i understand thats not as simple as creating an arbitrary partition and installing grub there

Comment: “thats not as simple as creating an arbitrary partition and installing grub there”—it actually pretty much is though. Just create a new EFI System Partition on the desired drive and you’re good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a bootable partition by making it UEFI System Partiton type

for that you can use a tool like fdisk on linux

for this example ill be assumeing drive path /dev/sda

first to enter fdisk do

```
fdisk /dev/sda
```

then to create a new partition

```
n
```

then enter the size 500 MB is 100% enough

```
+500M
```

print out the partitions to know witch one to edit

```
p
```

then to set partiton type

```
t
```

then enter in the partition number

```
1
```

and finally to set the type to UEFI system

```
1
```